# Delphi RAD Studio 10 Berlin WebBroker HTTP Port error - no peer with the interface with guid

Tags: rest, delphi, guid, peer, webbroker

I am using RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin, tried to create a REST sample application with following steps:

`New Project->Select Other->Web Server Application->Standalone Application->VCL Application->Port Number.`

I selected "Test Port" with 8080 and got this error:

`No peer with the interface with guid {} has been registered.`

I tried with different port number still got the same error.

Comment: More readable question, with spaces and code or steps highlighted

Comment: The question has an answer: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747533)

Comment: @nolaspeaker for future reference, when an answer to a question already exists, mark the question for close as a duplicate, don't just post a link to the duplicate in comments.